# M query - Edit the value of cell H2 in a table

Tags: powerbi, m

Having imported an excel sheet into power query, I need to tidy it up by changing the value of a particular cell.

At the moment that cell has a null value, but there are other null values in the same column that I do not want to change. – So I cannot replace all of the null values in that column with another value.

I also cannot correct that particular cell in the source excel file (there are hundreds of them, which were created before I arrived).

I basically need some syntax for example that sets the value of cell H2 to “Jeep”, but not to change any other cells.

Very grateful for any insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be:

In the Power Query Editor:

1. Add an index column starting from 1 (tab Add Column)
2. Add a Conditional column: If [Index] = 2 then Jeep else [H] (tab Add Column)
3. Delete Index column and [H] Column
4. Rename Custom column to [H].

Comment: True, but is there a way of doing this with just one line of syntax? (My predecessor built an excel data collection template that used merged cells for some of its column and row headings. - So I'd need to write a lot of code just to move a few cells around.)

Comment: I don't see the problem. The steps in my answer generate a script that you can easily re-use.